# How to Solve This Error In Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

Code:

```
public function init()
{
   global $cookie, $smarty, $cart, $iso, $defaultCountry, $protocol_link, $protocol_content, $link, $css_files, $js_files;

   if(!session_id()){
      if(!isset($_SESSION)){
         session_start();
      }
   }

   $cookie->id_cart=$_SESSION['pj_punchout_id'];

   if (self::$initialized)
      return;

   self::$initialized = true;

   $css_files = array();
   $js_files = array();
```

Error:

> Strict Standards: Creating default object from empty value in C:\xampp\htdocs\pjwebstoredev\classes\FrontController.php on line 82

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you're using Prestashop v1.4. The main problem I can see is that you've edited one of the core files, so most bets are off for the ability to support your code in the future. If you want to *cleanly* modify the behaviour of the core classes, then you should create an override called /override/classes/FrontController.php with the following contents:

```
class FrontController extends FrontControllerCore
{
    function init()
    {
        // Your additional custom init code goes here
        parent::init();
        // And/or additional custom init code goes here
    }
}
```

That's not the fundamental problems though, as we get to the next stage. The error you're seeing is because you are tring to use the global variable $cookie, but at a point in time before the variable is set to anything meaningful (the global cookie variable is actually initialised later in the very function you were modifying). Since you need to manipulate the cookie properties then you could try creating a temporary cookie object, use it to manipulate the user's cookie, then call the core code e.g.

```
class FrontController extends FrontControllerCore
{
    function init()
    {
        if ( !session_id() ) {
            if( !isset($_SESSION) ) {
              session_start();
            }
        }
        $cookieLifetime = (time() + (((int)Configuration::get('PS_COOKIE_LIFETIME_FO') > 0 ? (int)Configuration::get('PS_COOKIE_LIFETIME_FO') : 1)* 3600));
        $cookie = new Cookie('ps', '', $cookieLifetime);
        $cookie->id_cart=$_SESSION['pj_punchout_id'];

        parent::init();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Please send the solutions

Comment: Have you removed the changes from the original `/classes/FrontController.php` file, and created the override in `/override/classes/FrontController.php`? There may also be a problem with the fact that your code assumes that $_SESSION['pj_punchout_id'] is always set in the session, so try `if (isset($_SESSION['pj_punchout_id'])) $cookie->id_cart=$_SESSION['pj_punchout_id'];`

Comment: Hello  some error display                                                                 
Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\pjwebstoredev\classes\FrontController.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\pjwebstoredev\config\autoload.php on line 41

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\pjwebstoredev\config/../classes/FrontController.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\pjwebstoredev\config\autoload.php on line 41

Comment: It looks like you deleted the file `/classes/FrontController.php` - that needs to be there *as well as* your new `/override/classes/FrontController.php` You will also need to add `<?php` at the start of the second bit of code above and save that as the override file.

Comment: Another Error                                                               we have click the prestashop left side panel myaccout pannel click the my personal info tab?? Error the message displaying...how to fix????? 

Fatal error (Customer -> lastname is empty)